# Зачем google встраивает DRM контент на страницу поиска?

Tags: firefox, google-search, drm

Со вчерашнего дня браузер стал просить на странице поиска гугл включить DRM.
Зачем он там нужен? Что гугл пытается в браузер встроить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хоть версию браузера укажите. И список установленных расширений. Я такого не наблюдаю

Comment: А у вас DRM контент в настройках отключен? Браузер Firefox 70.0.1 + uBlock Origin 1.24.2 (и все).

Comment: Я пользуюсь Chrome и такой настройки не вижу